How to configure Spring Boot tests to test JPA and JDBC database access types using profiles in YAML file?
I having trouble running Spring Boot tests because I am either creating a JPA or JDBC connection to the database. However, I need to test both. I have configured the following in my YAML file:
spring:
profiles:
jpa:
app:
database-access-type: jpa
jdbc:
app:
database-access-type: jdbc
But it is not working. How can I properly configure Spring Boot tests to work with both JPA and JDBC database access types when using profiles in the YAML file?
spring: profiles: jpa: app: database-access-type: jpa jdbc: app: database-access-type: jdbc

annotations for test:
@SpringBootTest @Rollback @ActiveProfiles("jdbc")
But still there is configuration from my yml. This profiles are ignoring by Soprin

Solved, application-jdbc.yml & -jpa.yml.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
